# MySQL: grouping table per x / per y

Tags: php, mysql, sql, grouping

is it possible to do a single SQL query to group a table twice?

let's say i have a table of people belonging to different groups.
i want to see:

```
group1  males    14
group1  females  15
group2  males    23
group2  females  25
...
```

what's the best general approach to achieve this?
is it possible to do with a single query or do i need to use the UNION operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible in mysql....

```
Select * from table GROUP BY column1, column2
```

Answer (score 2):

yes it possible

```
group by your_group_column , gender
```